# Jenkins - Defining users

Tags: jenkins

I just installed jenkins in my pc. It is a Windows 7 and i used the
*.exe file.

Now i just run the msbuild using the targets: clean, init, compile,
test and coverage. After i have a windows batch command for run fxCop.

Now i want to configure security and users.

I'm using VisualSVN Server that has one user, sarasilva. I think
the best configuration in jenkins is to use the same users (?).

In the configuration i'm doing this:

http://s14.postimage.org/gvu930udd/security.png

In the people>sarasilva configuration i have this:

http://s15.postimage.org/y134g5q0b/security_sarasilva_config.png

If i save this configuration, when i try to log in with sarasilva user
this fails, i'm using the same password from the svn server.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an account - just permissions. Go to `http://<jenkins-host>/signup` and create the account.

Comment: i think i solved the problem. In the configuration i selected security and selected: Jenkins's own user database and Anyone can do anything, then i went to the people and selected the sarasilva user, and then the password field is available. Now i just can log in with this user....